PHP error log vanished (Windows Server 2019)
I have two Windows Server 2019 servers (in AWS) running Apache httpd 2.4.62, PHP 8.3.11 and SQL Server.  One is Dev/Test, the other Production.
I typically leave remote-desktop session open on both servers, and tail the PHP and Apache log files.
php.ini:
log_errors=On
error_log="C:\Windows\temp\php-errors.log"

Due to programming errors, the PHP error log existed; and I was monitoring to see if further errors occurred after making fixes.
A few days ago, the php-errors.log file vanished on both servers, on the same date.  The file no longer exists.
I see no evidence of hacking.  Searching the web I cannot find any reference to the error-log file disappearing.
Any suggestions about what might have happened, or how to investigate this problem?  Unfortunately I did not have Window Server Audit Policy enabled, so I cannot use that to determine who deleted the file.
Also there is nothing at all unusual in Windows Event Log, nor in Apache server log, nor in Apache access logs.

Is Storage Sense enabled in the Windows Server?


Is Storage Sense enabled in the Windows Server?

unfortunately not.
